# How to optimize performance of .net 5 application when working with mysql using Entity Framework Сore

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

My .net 5 application uses mysql database.
The work is done using the ORM Entity framework Core 5.0.11 and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2
Recently, I've been thinking about query performance.
The same query sent with applications and directly with mysql client (used workbench) has different execution time.
As a rule, requests from the workbench are executed two / three times faster.

Example:

```
_dbContext.SharepointFile.Create(
    new SharepointFile
    { 
        SharepointFileId = driveItem.Id,
        EmbedUrl = model.Link,
        Hash = hash,
    });
await _dbContext.SaveAsync();
```

Converted to a query like:

```
INSERT INTO `SharepointFiles` (`EmbedUrl`, `Hash`, `SharepointFileId`)
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
      SELECT `Id`
      FROM `SharepointFiles`
      WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `Id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This request from the application completes in **~0.58 sec** on average.
The same request sent from the Workbench client completes in **~0.2 sec**.

Another example of a simple data fetch:

```
SELECT `s`.`Id`, `s`.`EmbedUrl`, `s`.`Hash`, `s`.`SharepointFileId`
      FROM `SharepointFiles` AS `s`
      WHERE `s`.`Hash` = @__hash_0
      LIMIT 1
```

Runs from application in **~0.25 sec**.
From workbench in **~0.065sec**.

As you can see, these are simple, ordinary queries. Tell me what path to look for to optimize our application.
Perhaps there are thoughts about setting up a connection to mysql. I will provide details if needed.

Comment: Maybe turn off change tracking before you perform your inserts. This will improve your performance significantly. `_dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` But there maybe are negative effects from turning it off.

Comment: There are so many articles available on Google to resolve your problem. But anyways, I do agree with @SebastianSiemens - Try it and do let us know your findings.

Comment: Try run select twice, EF Core caches generated SQL. With EF Core you have to pay penalty for LINQ query translation.

Comment: Where are the machines?  What you showed should take 0.02 seconds or less.  So, I suspect network delays and/or other code in your app.

Comment: I agree with Rick. First check the latency between the machine that runs your app and the database and compare that to the latency between the machine that runs MySQL Workbench and the same database server that the app uses. Just run a couple of pings and take an average. Then post your results. -- What Svyatoslav said does only apply to the first query execution, because EF Core caches the translated query and reuses it. So consequtive executions don't get a performance hit from translating the LINQ expression to SQL.

Comment: @lauxjpn I deployed the application and mysql server locally to get rid of the network overhead in my tests. This is what I did. The first request with inserting data from the application was completed in **~0.13sec**. The same request from the workbench **~0.015sec**. it means the problem is in the code or is the EF core taking so long to process and translate the query to the database?

Comment: @АлександрКлимук The important benchmark is the *second+* request. Because on the first request, EF Core creates the model, opens the database connection, translates the query etc., which will always result in additional overhead and will be much slower than consecutive requests. Therefore, benchmark the query time of the *second* request (and also only the EF Core query time, not the full ASP.NET Core request time).

Answer (score 0):

When running a query in workbench will issue query against RDBMS and execute it there, so you're comparing after all running on the server to being apart, there will be difference.

That mentioned, when you do select, keep in mind if you need to modify data, and when not always use what Sebastian suggested with turning tracking off, see this performance piece on this,
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-and-asnotracking/

```
.AsNoTracking()
```

you really should be doing this a lot and I'd suggest doing that and then see where you are, remember to measure first and I bet you can document already huge improvements, and You will have achieved a lot if asked to improve performance.

If wanting to do more, consider making procedures, they can be called from EF.Core even if that will work very well in terms of using the effeciency of one with databinding capabilites of the other e.g.

```
_context.Set<Model>().FromSqlRaw("CALL spProcedure({0});", parametervalue).ToList<Model>();
```